# Extract/highlight everything inside a div tag include div tag itself with regex

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio-code

I'm after a regex code to highlight/extract everything inside the div tag include the closing match tag itself.

The problem is I'd like to extract a div tag with some specific information in its angle bracket ">"

For example, after filtering the results will show something like:

```
<div class="abc" id= "123">
bla bla bla

</div>
<div class="def" id = "456">
bla bla bla

</div>

<div class="hit" id = "789">
bla bla bla

</div>
```

Could anyone suggest how to extract/hightlight the matching regex in VSCode editor? I've installed the maching bracket plugin but when seaching for the tag it did not show the matching one.

Thank you very much

Comment: You want to select the content of the div and the `</div>` closing tag but not the div open tag? How complex can the content be?

Comment: I meant using regex to search for a div with class, and ID, and other properties. When these satisfied then retrieve everything between the <div class, ID, ..> contents </div>

Answer (score 0):

It is a 2 step process

1. search the `div` open tag with the right attributes, assume that the attributes are always in the same order and is the whitespace different.
   `<div class="[a-f]*?" id="2\d\d">`
   search all occurences (Alt+L from find dialog)
2. Press `Right Arrow`. Cursors are now right after the `div`-open tag
3. Use command `Emmet: Balance (outward)`